# What are some good ways of converting business logic errors to rest API errors?

Tags: api, rest, http, error-handling

I have a business logic layer that acts as a service and is agnostic to any application facing or user facing interface. For example, I've got UserService which takes care of operations related to user (e.x. creating users) and at the moment it returns a custom error object that includes a message that explains what went wrong. Now my RESTful API would use services to handle api requests but how do I handle business errors? how do I know what status code to use? I obviously don't like to put a lot of if statements in every single API call. I also thought about having a global error handler that would map every single business logic error to a status code and return that but that's also very verbose code. I'd love to hear some good ideas to handle this elegantly.

Comment: Here's a useful [guide](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/) for choosing an appropriate HTTP Status Code